# Generating two linked 2D array positions

Tags: python

I am creating a battleships game in Python. I am trying to generate a two position ship but the while loop that makes sure the positions are linked goes on forever. I am using Python 2.7

```
from random import randint
board = []
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)
print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)
def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
ship_row1 = random_row(board) + 1
ship_col1 = random_col(board) + 1
ship_row2 = random_row(board) + 1
ship_col2 = random_col(board) + 1
print "Generating ship..."
while (ship_row2 != ship_row1 + 1 or ship_row2 != ship_row1 - 1):
    ship_row2 = random_row(board) + 1
while (ship_col2 != ship_col1 + 1 or ship_col2 != ship_col1 - 1):
    ship_col2 = random_col(board) + 1
print ship_row1
print ship_col1
print ship_row2
print ship_col2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you have exchanged the `or` and `and` operators. Try to rethink the boolean logic behind your loops.

But... why don't you simply replace:

```
while (ship_row2 != ship_row1 + 1 or ship_row2 != ship_row1 - 1):
    ship_row2 = random_row(board) + 1
while (ship_col2 != ship_col1 + 1 or ship_col2 != ship_col1 - 1):
    ship_col2 = random_col(board) + 1
```

by:

```
ship_row2 = random.choice([ship_row1 + 1, ship_row1 - 1])
ship_col2 = random.choice([ship_col1 + 1, ship_col1 - 1])
```

so that you only chose between the two random positions you want instead of trying them all?

Comment: I didn't use "and" because I started with an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `and` instead of `or`

```
while (ship_row2 != ship_row1 + 1 and ship_row2 != ship_row1 - 1):
    ship_row2 = random_row(board) + 1
while (ship_col2 != ship_col1 + 1 and ship_col2 != ship_col1 - 1):
    ship_col2 = random_col(board) + 1
```

With `or`,  it's like  saying "Loop until `ship_row2` is equal to `ship_row1 +1` AND until `ship_row2` is equal to `ship_row1 -1`  which  is impossible.